# Weather forecast and probability of a bus to arrive at its destinations

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability

A bus is making its way to a destination. If the weather conditions are favorable today, the likelihood of delay is 3%. If the weather conditions are not favorable today, the likelihood of delay is 50%. The forecast predicts that it is 20% likely that the weather conditions will be favorable today.

1. What is the likelihood that the bus will be delayed?
2. The bus has arrived, but it was delayed. Given that the bus was delayed, what is the likelihood that the weather conditions were favorable?

My answers are:

Given that P(A) = the weather condition and P(B) = the likelihood of delay

1. `P(B|A⟯ = P(A∩B)/P(A) = 0.03/0.2 = 0.15 = 15%`
2. `(0.2 - 0.03)/0.2 = 0.85 = 85%`

Are my answers correct?

Comment: Of course it all depends on whether you really want to trust the weather forecast 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chance of delay is

(1)

$$[(0.2) \times (0.03)] ~+~ [(0.8) \times (0.5)] = .406.$$

---

(2)

R = event of Delay 
S = event of favorable conditions.

$$p(S|R) = \frac{p(\text{events}~ R~ \text{and} ~S ~\text{both occuring})}{p(R)}.$$

$$p(S|R) = \frac{0.006}{0.406}.$$